# How do I apply special group Exchange calendar permissions?

Tags: active-directory, security, exchange-2010

I've got an Active Directory Security Group with a number of people in it.  I'd like anyone in that group to be able to update each other's calendars.  How do I go about telling Exchange (2010) to do this?

Trying this:

```
Add-MailboxFolderPermission jimbob:\Calendar -User coolgroup -AccessRights Editor
```

Results in:

```
The specified mailbox "jimbob" doesn't exist.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (0:Int32) [Add-MailboxFolderPermission], ManagementObjectNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 182E7303,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.StoreTasks.AddMailboxFolderPermission
```

I've tried it with and without "-Identity", with full e-mail address, and by common name.  All do exactly the same thing.

Comment: What do you get if you try `get-mailbox jimbob`?

Comment: Same error, says it doesn't exist, even though it clearly shows up in the list returned by "Get-DistributionGroupMember coolgroup"...  I can also quite clearly see it in the system AD list.

Comment: Are you mailbox aliases the same as your AD usernames?

Comment: Yes, mailbox aliases match AD usernames.

Comment: Interesting. The fact that get-mailbox doesn't work either deserves its own question. Do you have multiple AD domains? Are you sure you're connected to the correct Exchange org? Is this Office 365 or other hosted Exchange provider? Open a new question with your errors and the answers to these questions.

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell one-liner:

```
Get-DistributionGroupMember groupName | Foreach-Object {
    Add-MailboxFolderPermission ($_.Alias + ":\Calendar") -User groupName -AccessRights Editor
}
```

Note that this applies the permission to the members currently in the group. Therefore:

- If you add anyone to the list, you'll need to run the command again.
- If you remove anyone, you'll need to manually remove the permission.

Comment: That's odd, my system claims that it doesn't recognize "Get-DistributionGroupMember" as a valid cmdlet.  Any special requirements for using it?

Comment: Are you running this from the Exchange Management Console?

Comment: No, I was doing it from a PowerShell command line.  I don't see a place inside of Exchange Management Console that allows me to insert and run scripts?

Comment: You need to run this within the Exchange Management SHELL, not console.

Comment: Well, interesting.  Getting errors about the specified mailbox not existing.  I've even tried it manually with a single one and all kinds of variations on the username (with domain, without, full name, etc).  I've confirmed that we are using "Calendar" as our folder name too.  I'm stuck again.  :-)

Comment: Edit your original post. Paste in the actual command you are using and the actual error.

Answer (score 1):

For each user, go to the security permissions of the calendar by right clicking it and going to "properties> permissions" in Outlook and add the group.  Grant the group the permissions as necessary.

Comment: Is there any way to apply this server side, or is client side modification the only way?  Would be nice to just do it on the server without having to contact each and every user and walk them through it.

Comment: Well, I finally gave in and tried to do it this way, but no dice.  It doesn't work for "normal" users, the sent events just silently disappear.  Users that are admins though, it works for...  Anything less than full admin privileges are insufficient, and giving everyone admin level is a non-starter.  :-(